# build error on Android: "error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setname_np'"

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, openh264

I always got the build error while compiling the [Openh264](https://github.com/jpxiong/openh264):

```
libopenh264.a(WelsThreadLib.o):WelsThreadLib.cpp:function WelsThreadSetName: error: undefined reference to 'pthread_setname_np'
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error if you've built OpenH264 targeting an android version >= 9 (2.3), but try to link your own shared library targeting an older version. You need build OpenH264 targeting at least as old version as your own application is targeting.

Comment: I simply use `NDK-BUILD` to start building. So how to build with version?

Comment: It picks the version to build your application code for from `jni/Application.mk` or `AndroidManifest.xml`. Also, for OpenH264, you can choose a version when you build it, e.g. `make OS=android NDKLEVEL=3` (where the default is 9).

Comment: Which property should be set in `jni/Application.mk` ?

Comment: In this case, set `APP_PLATFORM := android-9` in `jni/Application.mk`; then it should avoid this issue. If your application actually is supposed to run on Android versions lower than that, you need to rebuild OpenH264 to target a lower version instead.

Comment: It works fine for me after set `APP_PLATFORM := android-15` in `jni/Application.mk`. So accept and upvote the answer. Thanks.